# jQuery Isotope Table issue except Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am using jQuery plugin [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) for sorting and filtering. The data which is sorted and filtered is stored in a `<tr>` . The table is rendered perfectly and the functionality works fine in Firefox. But the table layout crashes in browsers except Firefox. I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Please help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).load(function() {

    var $container = $('.busResultsContainer').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.busResults',
      layoutMode: 'masonry',
      getSortData: {
        earliest: '[data-earliest] parseInt',
        late: '[data-earliest] parseInt',
        fastest: '[data-timeTaken] parseInt'
      },
      sortAscending: {
        earliest: true,
        late: false,
        fastest: true
      }
    });

    // Sorting Feature
    $(".sortByBtn").on("click", function() {
      sortByVal = $(this).data("sort-by");
      console.log(sortByVal);
      $container.isotope({
        sortBy: sortByVal
      });

    });

  });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(1),
.busResults td:nth-child(1),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(2),
.busResults td:nth-child(2),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(3),
.busResults td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15%;
}

.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(4),
.busResults td:nth-child(4),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(5),
.busResults td:nth-child(5),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(6),
.busResults td:nth-child(6),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(9),
.busResults td:nth-child(9) {
  width: 10%;
}

.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(7),
.busResults td:nth-child(7),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(8),
.busResults td:nth-child(8) {
  width: 7.5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary sortByBtn" data-sort-by="earliest">Earliest</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-info sortByBtn" data-sort-by="late">Latest</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-success sortByBtn" data-sort-by="fastest">Fastest</button>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <thead class="busResultsHeading">
      <tr>
        <th>Operators</th>
        <th>Bus Types</th>
        <th>Timing</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Distance</th>
        <th>Bus Number</th>
        <th>Seats</th>
        <th>Fare</th>
        <th>Schedule</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="busResultsContainer">
      <tr class="PublicTravels FastPassenger seatyes busResults col-md-12 padding00" data-earliest="1493001000" data-timetaken="180000">
        <td>
          Public Travels<br> Public Bus<br>
          <small class="bookinghr">Statue - Ernakulam</small>
        </td>
        <td>
          Fast Passenger
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="bookingfc">8:00 AM - 8:50 AM</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          0h 50m
        </td>
        <td>
          70 Km(s)
        </td>
        <td>PB 93 234</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>
          <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <b>40</b>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="view_schedule">View Schedule</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 mtop20 mbottom text-box table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bus Name: Public Bus</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Type: Fast Passenger</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Operator: Public Travels</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Number: PB 93 234</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:00</td>
                    <td>Statue</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:15</td>
                    <td>Vellayambalam</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:40</td>
                    <td>Kesavadasapuram</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:00</td>
                    <td>Attingal</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:10</td>
                    <td>Paravoor</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:30</td>
                    <td>Karunagapally</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:50</td>
                    <td>Chertala</td>
                    <td>80</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:50</td>
                    <td>Harippad</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:55</td>
                    <td>Ernakulam</td>
                    <td>140</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>09:00</td>
                    <td>Aroor</td>
                    <td>160</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="PublicTravels FastPassenger seatyes busResults col-md-12 padding00" data-earliest="1493029800" data-timetaken="306000">
        <td>
          Public Travels<br> Public Bus<br>
          <small class="bookinghr">Statue - Ernakulam</small>
        </td>
        <td>
          Fast Passenger
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="bookingfc">4:00 PM - 5:25 PM</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          1h 25m
        </td>
        <td>
          70 Km(s)
        </td>
        <td>PB 889</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>
          <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <b>40</b>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="view_schedule">View Schedule</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 mtop20 mbottom text-box table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bus Name: Public Bus</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Type: Fast Passenger</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Operator: Public Travels</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Number: PB 889</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>15:00</td>
                    <td>Statue</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>15:20</td>
                    <td>Vellayambalam</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>15:40</td>
                    <td>Kesavadasapuram</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>16:00</td>
                    <td>Attingal</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>16:15</td>
                    <td>Paravoor</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>17:10</td>
                    <td>Karunagapally</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>17:25</td>
                    <td>Chertala</td>
                    <td>80</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>17:35</td>
                    <td>Harippad</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>17:50</td>
                    <td>Ernakulam</td>
                    <td>140</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>18:00</td>
                    <td>Aroor</td>
                    <td>160</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="KedaramTravels LocalBus seatNo busResults col-md-12 padding00" data-earliest="1492984800" data-timetaken="252000">
        <td>
          Kedaram Travels<br> Kedaram Bus<br>
          <small class="bookinghr">Statue - Ernakulam</small>
        </td>
        <td>
          Local Bus
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="bookingfc">3:30 AM - 4:40 AM</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          1h 10m
        </td>
        <td>
          25 Km(s)
        </td>
        <td>KD 678</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
          <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <b>15</b>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="view_schedule">View Schedule</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 mtop20 mbottom text-box table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bus Name: Kedaram Bus</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Type: Local Bus</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Operator: Kedaram Travels</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Number: KD 678</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>02:05</td>
                    <td>Statue</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>02:15</td>
                    <td>Pattom</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>02:30</td>
                    <td>Kesavadasapuram</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>03:00</td>
                    <td>Kaniyapuram</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>03:30</td>
                    <td>Attingal</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04:25</td>
                    <td>Paravoor</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04:35</td>
                    <td>Kollam</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04:40</td>
                    <td>Chertala</td>
                    <td>60</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04:50</td>
                    <td>Alapuzha</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>05:00</td>
                    <td>Ernakulam</td>
                    <td>150</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="KedaramTravels LocalBus seatNo busResults col-md-12 padding00" data-earliest="1492998300" data-timetaken="126000">
        <td>
          Kedaram Travels<br> Kedaram Bus<br>
          <small class="bookinghr">Statue - Ernakulam</small>
        </td>
        <td>
          Local Bus
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="bookingfc">7:15 AM - 7:50 AM</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          0h 35m
        </td>
        <td>
          25 Km(s)
        </td>
        <td>KD 678</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
          <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <b>15</b>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="view_schedule">View Schedule</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 mtop20 mbottom text-box table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bus Name: Kedaram Bus</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Type: Local Bus</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Operator: Kedaram Travels</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Number: KD 678</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>06:00</td>
                    <td>Statue</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>06:10</td>
                    <td>Pattom</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>06:20</td>
                    <td>Kesavadasapuram</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>06:40</td>
                    <td>Kaniyapuram</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:15</td>
                    <td>Attingal</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:30</td>
                    <td>Paravoor</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:50</td>
                    <td>Kollam</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:50</td>
                    <td>Chertala</td>
                    <td>60</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:55</td>
                    <td>Alapuzha</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:00</td>
                    <td>Ernakulam</td>
                    <td>150</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/linktoahref/full/JNKgJZ/

Comment: Hey could you fix the layout?

Comment: @Zak what layout?

Comment: The table layout brother. The issue you posted.

Answer (score 0):

use this code your issue is resolve use tr position fixed

```
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <style>
 .hidden {
  display: none;
}

.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(1),
.busResults td:nth-child(1),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(2),
.busResults td:nth-child(2),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(3),
.busResults td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15%;
}

.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(4),
.busResults td:nth-child(4),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(5),
.busResults td:nth-child(5),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(6),
.busResults td:nth-child(6),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(9),
.busResults td:nth-child(9) {
  width: 10%;
}

.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(7),
.busResults td:nth-child(7),
.busResultsHeading tr th:nth-child(8),
.busResults td:nth-child(8) {
  width: 7.5%;
}
 .busResultsContainer{position: fixed!important; width: 100%;}
 </style>

 <body>
 <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).load(function() {

    var $container = $('.busResultsContainer').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.busResults',
      layoutMode: 'masonry',
      getSortData: {
        earliest: '[data-earliest] parseInt',
        late: '[data-earliest] parseInt',
        fastest: '[data-timeTaken] parseInt'
      },
      sortAscending: {
        earliest: true,
        late: false,
        fastest: true
      }
    });

    // Sorting Feature
    $(".sortByBtn").on("click", function() {
      sortByVal = $(this).data("sort-by");
      console.log(sortByVal);
      $container.isotope({
        sortBy: sortByVal
      });

    });

  });

});
</script>
<div style="display:block; width:100%;float:left;position: relative;">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary sortByBtn" data-sort-by="earliest">Earliest</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-info sortByBtn" data-sort-by="late">Latest</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-success sortByBtn" data-sort-by="fastest">Fastest</button>
</div>
<div style="display:block; width:100%;float:left;position: relative;">
<div class="table table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <thead class="busResultsHeading">
      <tr>
        <th>Operators</th>
        <th>Bus Types</th>
        <th>Timing</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Distance</th>
        <th>Bus Number</th>
        <th>Seats</th>
        <th>Fare</th>
        <th>Schedule</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="busResultsContainer" style="
    position: fixed!important;">
      <tr class="PublicTravels   seatyes busResults col-md-12 padding00" data-earliest="1493001000" data-timetaken="180000">
        <td>
          Public Travels<br> Public Bus<br>
          <small class="bookinghr">Statue - Ernakulam</small>
        </td>
        <td>
          Fast Passenger
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="bookingfc">8:00 AM - 8:50 AM</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          0h 50m
        </td>
        <td>
          70 Km(s)
        </td>
        <td>PB 93 234</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>
          <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <b>40</b>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="view_schedule">View Schedule</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 mtop20 mbottom text-box table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bus Name: Public Bus</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Type: Fast Passenger</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Operator: Public Travels</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Number: PB 93 234</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:00</td>
                    <td>Statue</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:15</td>
                    <td>Vellayambalam</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:40</td>
                    <td>Kesavadasapuram</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:00</td>
                    <td>Attingal</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:10</td>
                    <td>Paravoor</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:30</td>
                    <td>Karunagapally</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:50</td>
                    <td>Chertala</td>
                    <td>80</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:50</td>
                    <td>Harippad</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:55</td>
                    <td>Ernakulam</td>
                    <td>140</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>09:00</td>
                    <td>Aroor</td>
                    <td>160</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=" KedaramTravels LocalBus seatNo busResults col-md-12 padding00" data-earliest="1493029800" data-timetaken="306000">
        <td>
          Public Travels<br> Public Bus<br>
          <small class="bookinghr">Statue - Ernakulam</small>
        </td>
        <td>
          Fast Passenger
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="bookingfc">4:00 PM - 5:25 PM</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          1h 25m
        </td>
        <td>
          70 Km(s)
        </td>
        <td>PB 889</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>
          <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <b>40</b>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="view_schedule">View Schedule</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 mtop20 mbottom text-box table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bus Name: Public Bus</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Type: Fast Passenger</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Operator: Public Travels</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Number: PB 889</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>15:00</td>
                    <td>Statue</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>15:20</td>
                    <td>Vellayambalam</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>15:40</td>
                    <td>Kesavadasapuram</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>16:00</td>
                    <td>Attingal</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>16:15</td>
                    <td>Paravoor</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>17:10</td>
                    <td>Karunagapally</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>17:25</td>
                    <td>Chertala</td>
                    <td>80</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>17:35</td>
                    <td>Harippad</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>17:50</td>
                    <td>Ernakulam</td>
                    <td>140</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>18:00</td>
                    <td>Aroor</td>
                    <td>160</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="KedaramTravels LocalBus seatNo busResults col-md-12 padding00" data-earliest="1492984800" data-timetaken="252000">
        <td>
          Kedaram Travels<br> Kedaram Bus<br>
          <small class="bookinghr">Statue - Ernakulam</small>
        </td>
        <td>
          Local Bus
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="bookingfc">3:30 AM - 4:40 AM</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          1h 10m
        </td>
        <td>
          25 Km(s)
        </td>
        <td>KD 678</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
          <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <b>15</b>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="view_schedule">View Schedule</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 mtop20 mbottom text-box table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bus Name: Kedaram Bus</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Type: Local Bus</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Operator: Kedaram Travels</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Number: KD 678</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>02:05</td>
                    <td>Statue</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>02:15</td>
                    <td>Pattom</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>02:30</td>
                    <td>Kesavadasapuram</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>03:00</td>
                    <td>Kaniyapuram</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>03:30</td>
                    <td>Attingal</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04:25</td>
                    <td>Paravoor</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04:35</td>
                    <td>Kollam</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04:40</td>
                    <td>Chertala</td>
                    <td>60</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04:50</td>
                    <td>Alapuzha</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>05:00</td>
                    <td>Ernakulam</td>
                    <td>150</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="KedaramTravels LocalBus seatNo busResults col-md-12 padding00" data-earliest="1492998300" data-timetaken="126000">
        <td>
          Kedaram Travels<br> Kedaram Bus<br>
          <small class="bookinghr">Statue - Ernakulam</small>
        </td>
        <td>
          Local Bus
        </td>
        <td>
          <b class="bookingfc">7:15 AM - 7:50 AM</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          0h 35m
        </td>
        <td>
          25 Km(s)
        </td>
        <td>KD 678</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
          <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <b>15</b>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="view_schedule">View Schedule</a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 mtop20 mbottom text-box table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bus Name: Kedaram Bus</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Type: Local Bus</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Operator: Kedaram Travels</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Bus Number: KD 678</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                    <th>Distance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>06:00</td>
                    <td>Statue</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>06:10</td>
                    <td>Pattom</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>06:20</td>
                    <td>Kesavadasapuram</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>06:40</td>
                    <td>Kaniyapuram</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:15</td>
                    <td>Attingal</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:30</td>
                    <td>Paravoor</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:50</td>
                    <td>Kollam</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:50</td>
                    <td>Chertala</td>
                    <td>60</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>07:55</td>
                    <td>Alapuzha</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>08:00</td>
                    <td>Ernakulam</td>
                    <td>150</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div></div>
</body>

</html>
```